# Sending data back and forth between mysql and mssql

Tags: c#, php, mysql, sql

I'm in a situation where I have to retrieve data from mssql database and then perform inserts/updates on mysql. The language I'm using is PHP and I installed the Microsoft ODBC linux driver on my server to do this. The thing is it works but the performance isn't very great. What would be a better alternative ? Would it make any sense to write a wrapper in a compiled language like JAVA or C#.NET and then call it from PHP ?

Comment: You installed the `Microsoft ODBC linux driver` to talk to MSSQL is what you're saying right?

Comment: Yes I installed the Microsoft ODBC Linux Driver 1.0 on my linux server to talk to MSSQL.

Comment: Can you describe what you consider "not very great"? It is a ETL or something similar that constantly transfer information or something on-demand?

Comment: no. you need to find why you having performance problem.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you simply use the [`Mssql`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mssql.php) library in PHP. And per the [PHP documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mssql.requirements.php), use FreeTDS for the driver.